# Why use Navigation Controller as 1st item in storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm starting to learn iOS programming.

As I see im many tutorials and examples, the 1st item in `storyboard` is almost always a `Navigation Controller`, like in the image below:
[image]
My question is: what is the reason to always put a `Navigation Controller` as the first view controller? Like in the image above, I think that can remove the `Navigation Controller` and set the `Test Table View Controller` as the first view controller, so why need a `Navigation Controller` there?

Answer (score 0):

Because the navigation controller is what allows tapping a table cell to do a push segue to the next view controller.

Comment: It's sort of silly to downvote this answer, because it's correct. When devising an example, tutorials very often want a table view and a push when you tap a cell. But a push implies a navigation controller. Therefore table views very often live inside a navigation controller.

Comment: Sorry matt, it's not me who downvote your answer. Will upvote, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it's you. I'm just saying I'm right, and I'm trying to help. The reason table view examples are usually in navigation controllers is that the main thing you usually do with a table view is tap a cell to push to a new view controller, and that _requires_ a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Using Navigation Controller could let you make the push segue, It allows you to manage your views in a stack. It's OK to remove the Navigation controller, but you must use another segue to transform controllers.